# jquery and line breaks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Im doing a website project and having difficulty in finding the solution to my problem. On the index page of the project I am creating a background slider that pulls images from a folder on the server, this works fine, I would also like to have specified formatted text that is associated with each image displayed in sync with the images, as such I have created an overlay function that does this and pulls the text from php variable assigned, this works too, what I cannot seem to find is a solution that allows me to format the text with line breaks etc, 
whatever I have tried within the text and other functions either just replicates the line break

```
> ie : "some text'<br>'some other text" then gets dispayed as some
> text'<br>'some other text--.
```

I would like eventually like to pull this text from a database which i would do via php.
Following are the sepecific code im using to create this. Any help would be appreciated

php variable ************

```
<?php
    $text1 = "mandinga arts<br>new line";
?>
```

jquery function **************

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#index_slider").backstretch(["gallery/Slider/slider1.jpg", "gallery/Slider/slider2.jpg", "gallery/Slider/slider3.jpg","gallery/Slider/slider4.jpg", "gallery/Slider/slider5.jpg", "gallery/Slider/slider6.jpg", "gallery/Slider/slider7.jpg", "gallery/Slider/slider8.jpg"], {duration: 6000, fade: 750});
});
var texts = [ "<?php echo $text1?>", "Some text for Slide 2", "Some text for Slide 3", "Some text for Slide 4", "Some text for Slide 5","Some text for Slide 6", "Some text for Slide 7",  "Some text for Slide 8",]; $(window).on("backstretch.show", function (e, instance) { $(".overlay").text( texts[instance.index]); }); 
</script>
```

html***************

```
  <div id="index_slider" class="index_slider"></div>
  <div id="index_slider2" class="index_slider2"></div>  
    <div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$(".overlay").text( texts[instance.index]);
```

use

```
$(".overlay").html( texts[instance.index]);
```

for the browser to render your data as html.

Comment: so damn simple, really appreciate the help